# Eclipse/PyDev/GAE: How do I add command line options to my Run As->PyDev Google App Run

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I am using Eclipse/PyDev to develop a Google App Engine project called GAEServer. One of my common operations is to right click on the project and select Debug As->1 PyDev: Google App Run. Which kicks of a debug session for my application.

I would like to change the command line arguments executed when this command is invoked (to relocate where GAE local server looks for its database). This requires me to add arguments to the executed command.

If I select from the main menu: Run->Debug Configurations... there is an expandable item called PyDev Google App Run which contains a list of items:

```
PyDev Google App Run
GAEServer GAEServer
GAEServer GAEServer (1)
GAEServer GAEServer (2)
 ...
```

At the moment I have 19 of these which is a little surprising. If I select the first one then there is a tab where you appear to be able to add arguments `(x)= Arguments` but if I edit this and try to debug as again, it does not invoke GAE with the additional options, instead it creates another `GAEServer GAEServer (n)` with the default settings.

It may be that I have set up my project in some odd way, that I'm not understanding how this is supposed to work or that I have uncovered a bug. Can anyone help me figure out which?

Thanks in advance

Jules

Comment: I have  found this: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse.html which gives some help but still doesn't explain why multiple GAEServer GAEServer (n) are appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The run as will really create a new run configuration... Just erase the bunch of configurations you have, run it once and edit that one.

Later ( if you followed the suggestion on http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html ), you should be able to Ctrl+F11 to rerun the last launch done (or choose it from the menu: run > run history > previous launches: can be accessed through Alt+R, T, number of config).

Comment: Thank-you. I have managed to fix the problem with the pointer given here.

Comment: What I have done in the end is to create a new run/debug configuration and run it using the toolbar buttons rather than the pydev context menu option. This then works exactly as I expected.